# Finding maximal-sized rectangle inside circular segment

Tags: geometry, derivatives, quadratics, maxima-minima

Assume we have a circle with radius $r$ and its segment with height $v<r$. I want to fit in a rectangle whose area is the biggest. My approach was as follows:

Because $r>v$, we can describe a half circle with equation $f(x)=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}-(r-v)$. It is obvious that one of the vertices lies on this circle. Any point at the given circle has coords $[x,f(x)]$ We can then compute the area of such rectangle as follows: $A=2xf(x)$. To find the max, we define a new function $g(x)=2xf(x)$ for the derivative, we obtain: 
$$g'(x)=2\frac{-2x^2+r^2-(r-v)\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}$$
setting it equal to zero gives:
$$-2x^2+r^2-(r-v)\sqrt{r^2-x^2}=0$$
Here I am stuck. I tried to square root both sides (moving the square root to the right hand side) but that leaves me with really messy expression with $r,v$ in degrees $>2$. If i simplify, i get following equation in $x$:
$$4x^4+(-3r^2-2rv+v^2)x^2+2r^3v-v^2r^2$$
Using Discriminant tells me absolutely nothing about which of the two roots should i take (whether + or - $D$:
$$D=(-3r^2-2rv+v^2)^2-16(2r^3v-v^2r^2)$$
then:
$$x^2_{1,2}=\frac{3r^2+2rv-v^2\pm\sqrt{D}}{8}$$
What should i do next? Or would anyone give more elegant approach?

This picture should sum up, what I am dealing with
https://i.stack.imgur.com/spcuI.jpg
Let me explain what i added here.
Green is the equation of the circle,
Red is the function that we are finding the maximum of
Blue is its derivative
h(x) - orange is the polynomial i posted here in my steps
q(x) - purple is the polynomial after substituting $x^2\to x$

Comment: For one thing, I would reduce the clutter by setting $r=1$. Observe that $x$ only appears as $x^2$ in your equation for the critical points, so you can replace it with $z$. You might also try parameterizing the vertices on the circular arc by angle to see if that leads to something more tractable. You also have constraints on the values that $x$ can have that might bear on this.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i actually did and my solution to x^2 is given in the very last formula using the classical discriminant formula for quadratic equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation for a vanishing $g'(x)$ can be written as
$$
-2x^2+r^2=(r-v)\sqrt{r^2-x^2}.
$$
The right hand side is positive, while the left hand side is positive only if $2x^2<r^2$.

Setting $w=r-v$ (with $-r\le w\le r$) your solution can be written as:
$$
x^2=\frac{4r^2-w^2\pm\sqrt{w^4+8r^2w^2}}{8},
$$
that is:
$$
x^2=\frac{4r^2-w^2\pm|w|\sqrt{w^2+8r^2}}{8}.
$$
We can check that for the largest solution $2x^2>r^2$: 
$$
2x^2=\frac{4r^2-w^2+|w|\sqrt{w^2+8r^2}}{4}=
r^2+\frac{|w|\sqrt{w^2+8r^2}-w^2}{4}\ge r^2,
$$
where the equal sign holds only for $w=0$, in which case both solutions are the same. This cannot then be a valid solution and must be discarded.

Comment: That's a good argument, but how do i check that my solution with $+\sqrt{D}$ satisfies the inequality you gave

Comment: See my edited solution.

Answer (score 0):

We should choose the $x$ value with $-\sqrt{D}$. (This is because the other choice of $x$ value would not yield $g'(x)=0$. A straightforward way to check this is to calculate $D$, $x$, $g'(x)$ for specific values of the parameters $r$ and $v$ given in your assignment.)

For example, plugging in $r=10, \ v=1$, we find $D=9^2\cdot881$, and
$$
\max_{x>0}\{x (\sqrt{100 - x^2} - 10 + 1) \} 
= 190 \sqrt{38\over 235439 + 7929 \sqrt{881}} 
$$
at
$$ x =  \sqrt{ {319 - 9 \sqrt{881}\over8}},
$$

while
$$
\sqrt{ {319 + 9 \sqrt{881}\over8}} \approx 8.56 
$$
and 
$$
g' \left( \sqrt{ {319 + 9 \sqrt{881}\over8}} \right) \ne 0.
$$

Comment: The original assignment was $r=6$ and $v=5$ What i get then is that $$x^2_{1,2}=\frac{143\pm\sqrt{289}}{8}$$ But that's still saying nothing... Either solutions, when drawn graphically are obviously incorrect, because i can find a bigger rectangle anyways. Also I'm not interested in plugging in before I'm done with the general solution with variables.

Comment: Taking $-\sqrt{289}=-17$ and simplifying, we then have $x=3\sqrt{7}/2$. This checks out; try [this WolframAlpha command](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+x(sqrt(36-x%5E2)-6%2B5)+for+x%3E0) to verify.

Comment: Taking the + yields $160/8=20$ therefore $x=\sqrt{20}=2\sqrt{5}$... Still valid

Comment: Look, i edited my original post and added the picture of my graphs. You can see that the orange polynomial intersects the x axis in two points. Taking $+\sqrt{D}$ resulting in the right one, $-\sqrt{D}$ in the left one. The actual extrema of my $g(x)$ is the $-\sqrt{D}$. What i was interested in, how could i reason this fact..."by looking at graph" is not a good reason i would say

Comment: Without looking at the graphs, we can check that $g'(x)=0$ for $x=3\sqrt{7}/2$ - but $g'(x)<0$ for $x=\sqrt{20}$.